# how to embed jQuery in VueJS for formBuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I got problem that I don't know why `jQuery` plugin error not found even I've already installed it.

I'm planning to use that `formBuilder` for my VueJS project
https://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started

and in my HelloWord.vue file,

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = $.extend(require('jquery-ui'));
import formBuilder from 'formBuilder';
```

I did like that but I got following error message. Please let me know how to solve it, thanks.

```
form-builder.min.js?f008:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at eval (form-builder.min.js?f008:19)
    at Object../node_modules/formBuilder/dist/form-builder.min.js (app.js:1678)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:727)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:4)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it through `new Webpack.ProvidePlugin` in webpack.

```
const Webpack = require('webpack')

// ...
plugins: [
  new Webpack.ProvidePlugin ({
    $: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
],
```

**Update**

If you use vue-cli 3, modify the `vue.config.js` file as follows:

```
const Webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  configureWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,
      new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

In addition, enter the command in the terminal to set up the entire webpack. This generates webpack.txt.

```sh
vue inspect > webpack.txt
```

Comment: i'm using vue `3.11.0` hence it's using with `babel.config.js`

Comment: With vue-cli 3, you can override the settings for webpack in vue.config.js. Your answers have been corrected.

Comment: there is no `vue.config.js`, only have `babel.config.js`

Comment: Try making and using `vue.config.js`. If `vue.config.js` is at the project root, they are automatically loaded. https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#target-browsers. `babel.config.js` is a setup file for a `babel`